# Multiplying two summarized formulas in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a grouped Crystal report.  In the inner group I have a couple formulas that get summarized to display values.  I was wondering if there is a way in Crystal reports to multiply the values of these two formulas similar like in Reporting services that I would use something like: ReportItems!Textbox1.Value * ReportItems!Textbox2.Value.  Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

At first I was thinking this was the common scenario like `wage * hours_worked` where you'd want `sum of (wage * hours)`, which is NOT the same as what you're asking, equivalent to `sum_of_wage * sum_of_hours_worked`.

One way of accomplishing this would be to create a stored procedure or view in your data source that has the value you want directly, then just access that value in your report anywhere you want.

Comment: Of course formulas can access summary fields - you can use sum({tbl.field}, "groupname") and similar functions.

Comment: @Arvo - gah, must be the lack of sleep, not sure how I missed that. I will edit the error out of my answer and you can add the simpler answer of using a formula as you reminded me...